# How to apply both ValidationPipe() and ParseIntPipe() to params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs

I'm trying to apply both the `ValidationPipe()` and `ParseIntPipe()` to the params in my NestJs controller.

The intention is to apply `ParseIntPipe()` only on `@Param('id')` but `ValidationPipe()` for all params in `CreateDataParams` and Body DTO.

However, I can't seem to apply both pipes the way I wanted. Here's what I have:

```
@Post(':id')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
async create(
    @Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id: number,  //this doesn't work
    @Param() params: CreateDataParams,
    @Body() createDto: CreateDto
) {
    // params.id
}
```

I have tried having another `@Param('id')` to apply the `ParseIntPipe()` transformer but this doesn't work.

How can I apply both `ValidationPipe()` and `ParseIntPipe()` to the params?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you apply the `ParseIntPipe` to the `id` param, it will only transform `id` but not the property `id` of `params`, here it will stay a `string`.

Instead, you can use `class-transformer` to transform your param to a `number`:

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
export class CreateDataParams {
  @Transform(id => parseInt(id), {toClassOnly: true})
  id: number;
}
```

Then you use the `ValidationPipe` with the option `transform: true`:

```
@Post(':id')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
async create(
    @Param() params: CreateDataParams,
    @Body() createDto: CreateDto
) {
    // params.id
}
```

Note though, that this is unsafe because e.g. `parseInt('5abc010')` is `5`. So you might want to do additional checks in your transformation function.

Comment: Oh thanks! I did not think of this. This worked very well!

Comment: I used @Transform(role => JSON.parse(id), {toClassOnly: true}) but its not working, any idea?

Comment: @KallolMedhi Did you set `transform: true` in your `ValidationPipe`?

Comment: Also, `id` is `undefined` in the function `role => JSON.parse(id)`. You have to change the name of the param.

Comment: @KimKern yea it worked now, i had to set transform: true in global validation pipe. Also can you tell me the difference between 'toClassOnly' and 'toPlainOnly' what should I do in my case??

i just have to parse a particular field in the body before it reaches DTO and validation

Comment: I think its best to refer the document in these cases, but anyway - 'toClassOnly' the transformation that you have done will be applied only when the plainJSON is transformed to a class (kind of when serialzed). 'toPlainOnly' is vice versa