# No metadata found for class-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I am trying to use a `ValidationPipe` but no matter how I write my code I get the following warning when sending a request: `No metadata found. There is more than once class-validator version installed probably. You need to flatten your dependencies`.

My route looks something like this:

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
async findAll(@Query() queryDto: QueryDto) {
    return await this.myService.findAll(queryDto);
}
```

And my DTO looks something like this:

```
export class queryDto
{
    @ApiModelProperty({
        description: 'Maximum number of results',
        type: Number,
        example: 50,
        default: 50,
        required: false
    })
    readonly limit: number = 50;
}
```

I tried using the `ValidationPipe` several ways, following [the doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes), but nothing works for me. I know it does not work because although the request gets a response, the default value that I wrote in my DTO for the property `limit`, which is `50`, is not used when the query is empty. Therefore, when no `limit` is provided in the query, `limit`'s value is undefined, whereas it should be `50` (which means the `ValidationPipe` is not used).

My `package.json` seems correct:

```
npm ls class-validator
api-sport@0.0.1 /home/pierre_t/Bureau/dev/ApiSport
└── class-validator@0.9.1
```

Full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "api-sport",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "start:prod": "pm2 start ./src/main.js --no-daemon",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.3",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "pm2": "^3.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.7.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Why do I get this message and how can I use `ValidationPipe`?

Comment: Can you add your `package.json`? It seems that you have multiple version of `class-validator` in your `node_modules`.

Comment: @KimKern I updated my answer with relevant informations concerning my `package.json`

Comment: Please post your complete `package.json`. It can be a sub-dependency of another library you used.

Comment: You can also try `npm ls class-validator`

Comment: @KimKern I added the whole file + npm ls

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because you are using `class-validator` but without any validations, see this [issue](https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql/issues/150#issuecomment-420181526):

> Basically, it warns that you don't have any metadatas in the storage,
>   which means you haven't used any decorator from class-validator. That
>   means you don't perform any validation, so you should just pass
>   `validate: false` option to `buildSchema` to disable automatic validation.

I'm not sure if you can turn of validation for nest's `ValidationPipe`, but alternatively you can just add an assertion to your dto (if it makes sense), e.g.:

```
import { Min } from 'class-validator';
export class QueryDto {
    @Min(1)
    readonly limit: number = 50;
}
```

---

By the way: Since your `@Query` will only have string properties, you'll probably want to transform your `limit` from `string` to `number`. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480830/4694994).

Comment: What is `buildSchema`? Where do I find/declare it?

Comment: (somehow, after trying what you suggested, I **cannot** manage to get `undefined` again. I reverted my code back to the version where I got `undefined` as default value, but I don't get `undefined` anymore, I get the default value, even without class-validator, and without a ValidationPipe. Wtf? That's black magic. But that's just a detail, my problem is pretty much solved it seems)

Comment: Glad it's working for you now. :-) I've just tried it without the `ValidationPipe` and it doesn't set default values for me. Important for setting the default value is that your dto class is actually instantiated. Otherwise it will be a plain javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered, but for future reference of people with the same problem...

The [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) allows you to bypass the validation of certain property ([**whitelisting**](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting)) special flags to validate any property.

As the [docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting):

> This will strip all properties that don't have any decorators. If no
>   other decorator is suitable for your property, you can use **@Allow**
>   decorator

e.g:

```
import {validate, Allow, Min} from "class-validator";

export class Post {

    @Allow()
    title: string;

    @Min(0)
    views: number;

    nonWhitelistedProperty: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my **bootstrap**, it works with *class-validator*:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share here a solution for another situation which provokes the same error. (Error comes from `class-validator` package as mentioned above, `0.14.1` version in my case)

If you import only the typescript type of DTO class and use it with a nest param decorator (`@Body`, `@Query` etc.), you will get the same error:

```js
/** this fails */
import {Body} from '@nestjs/common';
import type {CreatePageDto} from './pages/dto/create-page.dto';

createPage(@Body() pageDto: CreatePageDto) { ... }
```

`class-validator` use reflection to access class constructor, so you need to remove 'type' in the `CreatePageDto` import:

```js
/** this works */
import {Body} from '@nestjs/common';
import {CreatePageDto} from './pages/dto/create-page.dto';

createPage(@Body() pageDto: CreatePageDto) { ... }
```

It is not obvious from the text of this error message, so I hope it helps someone.