# Boolean parameter in request body is always true in NestJS api

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

Consider this endpoint in my API:

```js
@Post('/convert')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  convert(
    @UploadedFile() image: any,
    @Body(
      new ValidationPipe({
        validationError: {
          target: false,
        },
        // this is set to true so the validator will return a class-based payload
        transform: true,
        // this is set because the validator needs a tranformed payload into a class-based
        // object, otherwise nothing will be validated
        transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
      }),
    )
    parameters: Parameters,
  ) {
    return this.converterService.start(image, parameters);
  }
```

The body of the request, which is set to `parameters` argument, contains a property called `laserMode` that should be a boolean type, it is validated like such on the **parameters DTO**:

```js
  @IsDefined()
  @IsBoolean()
  public laserMode: boolean;
```

now the strange part, when a send a request from PostMan where:

1. `laserMode = false`
2. `laserMode = cool` (a string other the  boolean value)

I noticed that `laserMode` is **always set to true** and this is after the validation process is completed because when I *console.log* the instance of Parameter in the constructor of the class

```js
export class Parameters {
  ...
  constructor() {
    console.log('this :', this);
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't see the property!

> **Note**: when `laserMode` is removed from the request, the expected validation errors are returned (should be defined, should be boolean value).

```js
// the logged instance 'this' in the constructor
this : Parameters {
  toolDiameter: 1,
  sensitivity: 0.95,
  scaleAxes: 200,
  deepStep: -1,
  whiteZ: 0,
  blackZ: -2,
  safeZ: 2,
  workFeedRate: 3000,
  idleFeedRate: 1200,
  laserPowerOn: 'M04',
  laserPowerOff: 'M05',
  invest: Invest { x: false, y: true }
}
// the logged laserMode value in the endpoint handler in the controller
parameters.laserMode in controller : true
// the logged laser value from the service
parameters.laserMode in service : true
```

- misspelling is checked
- same result is noticed when using a Vue app instead of postman.
  So!!?

Answer (score 53):

Found a workaround for the issue with class-transformer

You can use this:

```
@IsBoolean()
@Transform(({ value} ) => value === 'true')
public laserMode: boolean;
```

This will transform the string into a boolean value, based on if it is 'true' or any other string. A simple workaround, but every string different than true, results in false.

Answer (score 20):

This is how I got round the issue while managing to keep the boolean typing.

By referring to the original object by key instead of using the destructured value.

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

const ToBoolean = () => {
  const toPlain = Transform(
    ({ value }) => {
      return value;
    },
    {
      toPlainOnly: true,
    }
  );
  const toClass = (target: any, key: string) => {
    return Transform(
      ({ obj }) => {
        return valueToBoolean(obj[key]);
      },
      {
        toClassOnly: true,
      }
    )(target, key);
  };
  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    toPlain(target, key);
    toClass(target, key);
  };
};

const valueToBoolean = (value: any) => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
    return value;
  }
  if (['true', 'on', 'yes', '1'].includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
  }
  if (['false', 'off', 'no', '0'].includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
    return false;
  }
  return undefined;
};

export { ToBoolean };
```

```js
export class SomeClass {
  @ToBoolean()
  isSomething : boolean;
}
```

Comment: not sure which version of `Transform` you were using, I had to change it slightly to:
     
  const toPlain = Transform(
    (value) => {
      return value;
    },
    {
      toPlainOnly: true,
    }
  );
  const toClass = (target: any, key: string) => {
    return Transform(
      (value) => {
        return valueToBoolean(value);
      },
      {
        toClassOnly: true,
      }
    )(target, key);
  };
  return function (target: any, key: string) {
    toPlain(target, key);
    toClass(target, key);
  };
    };

Comment: What version are you folks using? I'm on v0.4.0. Have you tried FoosMaster's suggestion? The documentation for your versions Transform function should let you know what you have access to. In my case I do indeed have access to the original object and the property within the object which is why it works. You can refer to the value with obj[key]

Comment: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#advanced-usage

Answer (score 18):

This is due to the option `enableImplicitConversion`. Apparently, all string values are interpreted as `true`, even the string `'false'`.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/306) requesting a changed behavior for `class-transformer`.

Comment: ok, but without it, the validation always fails for all rules of DTO properties'. should I convert to a string instead of boolean?

Comment: You can control the conversion by using the `@Transform` annotation instead, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480830/4694994

Comment: thank for the answer but I converted the property to a string instead of boolean and saved my self from a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 8):

did you find a permanent solution for this?
I solved it with this hack:

```
@IsBoolean()
@Transform(({ obj, key }) => obj[key] === 'true')
laserMode: boolean;
```

An improved version in case you want to have use of the `@IsBoolean` is to do the following:

```
  @Transform(({obj, key}) => {
    return obj[key] === 'true' ? true : obj[key] === 'false' ? false : obj[key];
  })
  @IsBoolean()
  laserMode?: boolean = true;
```

This will return the value if for example someone send `laserMode='anything'`

Comment: Unfortunately no i didn't (at the time that i asked this question), but you can check the answer of David Kerr.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to receive both true/false,
then use the below solution.
It will mark all `true` for defined values
and mark it as false for all others

```
@Transform(({ value }) => {  
  return [true, 'enabled', 'true', 1, '1'].indexOf(value) > -1;  
})  
mode: boolean;
```

Avoid using below decorators as they don't work well enough

```
@IsBoolean()  
@Type(() => Boolean)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73273432/query-model-is-not-able-to-pick-all-parameters-from-query-string

Answer (score 3):

We resolved this issue like this. Sometimes Transform runs twice.

```
@Transform(({ obj, key }) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return obj[key] === 'true';
    }

    return value;
  })
laserMode: boolean;
```

Comment: After trying many proposed solutions, this one worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. For now, it's a better option to go with.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem with a NestJS controller, based on other answers, here's how I solved it:

```
@IsDefined()
@Transform(({ value }) => value === 'true' ? true : value === 'false' ? false : value)
@IsBoolean()

public laserMode: boolean;
```

Tested:

- Ok for values: true or false
- Other values:

  "message": [
  "laserMode must be a boolean value"
  ]

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is related to class-transformer, not Nestjs itself.

do these steps:

first enable transform in ValidationPipe for the app:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

then in dto use customer transform like this: (you can ignore validation and swagger decorators)

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsBoolean, IsOptional, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class UploadMediaOptionsDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsBoolean()
  @Transform((val: string) => [true, 'enabled', 'true', 1, '1'].indexOf(val) > -1)
  public generateThumbnail: boolean = true;
}
```

and disable enableImplicitConversion.

it should transform the types based on the decorators, i.e. @IsInt() should attempt to transform a string to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same kind of the problem when parsing a boolean query parameter. And  I found the problem caused by class-validate itself. It alway transform the value to `true`.

With the `@Transform` decoratror, I printed the transformed value and raw value of the this DTO item. You can see that the transformed value is always `true` no matter the raw value is `'true'` or `'false'`

```
...
  @IsBoolean()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform((object) => {
    console.log(object);
    return object.value;
  })
  isMuted?: boolean;
...
```

[image]

Obviously, the `@Transform` provides the access to the raw query parameters, which means you can use the `obj` item to get the boolean parameter to complete transformation correctly, in my case it can done like this

```
{
...
  @IsBoolean()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(({ obj }) => {
    return obj.isMuted === 'true';
  })
  isMuted?: boolean;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good. Its also possible to do this.

```
@IsBoolean()
@Type(() => Boolean)
something: boolean
```