# Why should we NOT use enableImplicitConversion when using class-transformer?

Tags: class-validator, class-transformer

The [class-transformer docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#implicit-type-conversion) say:

> **Implicit type conversion**
>   NOTE If you use class-validator together with class-transformer you propably DON'T want to enable this function.

Why not?

I did some tests and found no issues.
Actually it is the other way around: using [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) (with `enableImplicitConversion=true` and [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata)) in combination with [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) seems to be a perfect fit and it is supported out-of-the-box by [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some reasons why we should **not** use implicit conversion.

## It is too lenient

e.g. when we use `@IsString()` every type will pass the validation - even a plain object will be converted to the string `[object Object]`, which is probably not what you want

here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-validate-transform)

## `@Transform()` may not work

Example:

```js
class Test {
  @Transform(value => (value === "zero" ? 0 : value), {
    toClassOnly: true
  })
  val: number;
}
const transformed = plainToClass(Test, {
    val: 'zero'
  }, {
    enableImplicitConversion
  });

// transformed.val = NaN
```

The problem here is that the implicit conversion is already happening before `@Transform()` and since it cannot convert the string to a number it sets the value to `NaN`

[Transform Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-validate-transform-2?file=index.ts)

Comment: Also, you might have issues with booleans, as the value 'false' will be interpreted as true. see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046629/boolean-parameter-in-request-body-is-always-true-in-nestjs-api

Comment: Ok, so what is the best approach then? Without it NestJs acts stupid, so you need a lot of times