# How to validate an array of objects in nestjs using dto

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I am trying to validate an array of objects using DTO in nestjs. I have tried it but the data is not getting validated. I tried to search a lot but didn't get any answer.
These are my files:

trivia.controller.ts file

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, ParseArrayPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoggerService } from '../logger/logger.service';
import { TriviaService } from './trivia.service';
import { PostTriviaScoreDto } from './dto/post-trivia-score.dto';

@Controller('trivia')
export class TriviaController {
  constructor(private readonly logger: LoggerService, private readonly triviaService: TriviaService) {}

    @Post('score')
    postTriviaScore(@Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: PostTriviaScoreDto })) postTriviaScoreDto: PostTriviaScoreDto) {
        this.logger.info('Trivia Controller : postTriviaScore : start');
        return this.triviaService.postTriviaScore(postTriviaScoreParamsDto, postTriviaScoreDto);
    }
}
```

trivia.service.ts file

```
import { LoggerService } from '../logger/logger.service';
import { PostTriviaScoreDto } from './dto/post-trivia-score.dto';

 @Injectable()
export class TriviaService {
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
  ) {}
    postTriviaScore(allPlayersTriviaScore: PostTriviaScoreDto) {
            this.logger.info('Trivia Service : postTriviaScore : start');
            console.log('allPlayersScore ', allPlayersTriviaScore);
    
    }
}
```

post-trivia-score.dto.ts file

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsUUID, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

class TriviaScore {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsUUID()
  question_id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsUUID()
  selected_option_id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  answered_in_time: number;
}

export class PostTriviaScoreDto {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => TriviaScore)
  items: TriviaScore[];
}
```

Structure of my JSON

```
[
  {
    "question_id": "088f1344-061e-4bcc-966f-512775f1f082",
    "selected_option_id": "72305e08-fedd-49b1-adb9-1dd92c88f4db",
    "answered_in_time": 2
  }
]
```

The properties are not getting validated here. Even if I pass a string in answered_in_time field, it accepts the body and doesn't throw an error or if I  pass empty string in any of the fields then also it accepts the request body.

Please help me if you guys know the solution as I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

I think the nested class there is not initialised and use it for type reference only so class-transformer does not know how to convert it to class instance.

set `enableImplicitConversion: true` can request `class-transformer` to convert it implicitly

**main.ts**

```js
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true, // allow conversion underneath
      },
    }),
);
```

After that, the nested properties should be able to be validated.

---

Some said implicit conversion may have problem on other cases but I cannot find a clean solution if class is not instantiated:

[Why should we NOT use enableImplicitConversion when using class-transformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531427/why-should-we-not-use-enableimplicitconversion-when-using-class-transformer)

Comment: Is there a way to set it for only one property? So that if there are any issues, they would be limited to that specific property and not affect all the system.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced such problem and after googling I have fount that using

```
new ParseArrayPipe({items: YourDto, whitelist: true})
```

in controller. You also did this, you said body would be array but your dto is not array actually

```
postTriviaScoreDto: PostTriviaScoreDto // --> mistake
```

If you did:

```
postTriviaScoreDto: PostTriviaScoreDto[] // this will solve your problem
```

Information is taken from this [website](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/validate-array-object-swagger-nestjs/)

Comment: This is also documented in Nestjs's [official doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#parsing-and-validating-arrays).